# MAUI App Failed to Install (Local device) when built in Release mode

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am new to .NET maui, When I try to run my ecommerce app (MVVM databinding)(debug mode) to my locally connected phone then all fine(installing succefully).
But When I change to Release mode and try the same then I am getting error in vs2022 17.5-P1 is that "Failed to install APK".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across the same issue and solved it by disabling compiled bindings either globally or at least those that are bound to the class.

e.g)

```
[XamlCompilation (XamlCompilationOptions.Skip)]
public partial class HomePage: ContentPage
{
…
}
```

Comment: disabling compiled binding is fixed the issue.

Comment: Could you check if this issue has been reported already in the MAUI repository: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues? If not, please create a new issue using the bug template, because compiled bindings should also work in Release mode.